# hugo: build static site with Google Cloud Build

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, hugo

I would like to automatically build a Docker container that displays the public files of a website created with the Hugo framework.
Therefore I added the following `Dockerfile` to the root directory of the Hugo website:

```
FROM klakegg/hugo:0.104.3-onbuild AS hugo

FROM nginx
COPY --from=hugo /target /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The idea of this multi-stage build is to create the website files on the fly and display the result using a nginx container.
When I create the container locally on my Ubuntu 20.04 Linux PC and then run it, everything works as expected and the website is available at `localhost:8080`:

```
docker build -t hugo-local .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 hugo-local
```

If I built the container with Google Cloud Build, the build process completes successfully. The files are also copied to the correct directory (`/usr/share/nginx/html`).

```
steps:
# This step builds the container image.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Build
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '-t'
  - 'eu.gcr.io/gcp-project/hugo-cloud:$BUILD_ID'
  - '.'

# This step pushes the image to Container Registry
# The PROJECT_ID and SHORT_SHA variables are automatically
# replaced by Cloud Build.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Push
  args:
  - 'push'
  - 'eu.gcr.io/gcp-project/hugo-cloud'
```

However, instead of rendering the website, the default nginx welcome page is displayed:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 hugo-cloud
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?
Feedback highly appreciated.

I tried various base images, various environments.

Comment: It's difficult to help because your question doesn't include a minimal repro nor details that support your claims (e.g. "The files are also copied to the correct directory"). How are your running `gcloud build submit`?  You show the same `docker run ... hugo-cloud` command with different results which is confusing. The container image built by Cloud Build will be `eu.gcr.io/gcp-project/hugo-cloud:${BUILD_ID}` not `hugo-cloud`. Generally you want to use [`images`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#images) rather than include a `docker push` step.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are of course right I tried to keep it general. Here you can find the link to the corresponding repository:
https://github.com/smichard/hugo_website

To build the container with GCP cloud build I tried several things. First I tried `gcloud builds submit`, second I created a trigger in GCP for the GitHub repository. After that the container was built automatically. Both give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

I used one of my own Hugo sites:

```bash
git clone \
--recurse-submodules \
git@github.com:me/repo.git
```

I can run my site:

```bash
hugo server -D
```

And:

```bash
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=${PWD}:/src \
--publish=1313:1313 \
docker.io/klakegg/hugo:0.104.3 \
  server -D
```

To your question, I added `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` files.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM klakegg/hugo:0.104.3-onbuild AS hugo

FROM nginx
COPY --from=hugo /target /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And I built and was able to run the site:

```bash
podman build \
--tag=snippets:$(git rev-parse HEAD) \
--file=./Dockerfile \
${PWD}

podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
snippets:$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  id: build
  args:
  - build
  - --tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hugo-cloud:${BUILD_ID}
  - '.'

#- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
#  id: push
#  args:
#  - push
#  - gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hugo-cloud:${BUILD_ID}

images:
- gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hugo-cloud:${BUILD_ID}
```

> Both approaches to the `push` work (your way) `docker push` and the default Cloud Build way of enumerating `images`.

Build it:

```bash
gcloud builds submit ${PWD} \
--config=cloudbuild.yaml \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Get the most recent Build ID as `TAG` and run the container:

```bash
TAG=$(\
  gcloud builds list \
  --limit=1 \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(id)")

podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=8080:80 \
gcr.io/${PROJECT}/hugo-cloud:${TAG}
```

That works too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. They have helped me and helped to narrow down the problem.
In fact, the problem still persists as soon as I set up a continuous deployment. As soon as I create a trigger at Google Cloud Build and link it to the GitHub repository. Then the nginx default page is still displayed.
When I create the container using Google Cloud Builds with `google builds submit`, everything works as intended.